# Request for help getting Stripe Payment Processor working in CiviCRM/Wordpress

Tags: stripe, payment

I'm testing Stripe for payment processing in CiviCRM.

I have the latest Stripe Payment Processor extension (4.7.3)

And I'm running Wordpress 4.9.4/CiviCRM 4.7.27

I have a user side payment page that when I put in all the test data, and press the "Confirm Contribution" button, nothing happens, except the button changes to "Submitted".

I can't see any errors in the CiviCRM depug log in wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ConfigAndLog

As far as I know, I'm using the correct API settings for test mode in Stripe.

My Stripe API version is 2018-02-06. And because this is a new Stripe account, I can't select an older API to see if that works.

This same non-activity happens whether i'm on the user side, or on the CiviCRM Admin side.

I don't know where to look to find errors, because all the usual places I would look don't seem to be showing errors...

Thanks for any help,
Norman

Comment: To add to this. If I leave information out, then the same thing happens. ie nothing. It doesn't go through the validation step.

Comment: I created a Dummy Payment processor, and that DOES go through the validation step. 

So it seems that there's something going weird when the Stripe Payment processor is used. ie. It's not just a generic problem with the submission form.

Answer (score 1):

Soooo....

I found the problem. My API key had managed to get spaces in it, presumably when I copied it from the Stripe interface. I didn't see the spaces because the text is obfuscated like a password.

The fact it had spaces was causing a Javascript error. Which didn't come up ANYWHERE in the interface, until I had the Chrome developer tools open. And I suddenly noticed the error on the console.

Ultimately, it would be really helpful if such errors were reported to the user. Possibly only when CiviCRM debug mode is on.

But not displaying those errors meant I wasted a whole bunch of time trying to track the problem down... :-(

Cheers,
Norman

Comment: Thanks for following up! I recommend adding this in the extensions issue queue: https://github.com/drastik/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/issues